# Service Unavailable occuring even when app_offline.htm in use

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, app-offline.htm

I have an ASP.NET site hosted on shared hosting so direct access to logs is unavailable.

The site has been stable but recently it's been going down every few minutes with a "Service Unavailable" message. Funny thing is, I will also encounter this issue is the app_offline.htm page is in use leading me to believe the issue is not with my site but the hosting environment.

The site is hosted under IIS6. Any ideas how to investigate such an issue, or what might be causing the issue?

Comment: I find that error occurs when you have one or more web applications that use different .Net Framework versions in the same application pool in IIS. Check the app pool and framework version, and make sure none of the other apps in the app pool are on a different framework version.

Comment: @heathesh - Thanks for that, I'll run it by their support guys to see if multiple sites are sharing the app pool using different frameworks.